# How to find "rain" in a variable for openweathermap

Tags: python, openweathermap

I am trying to make a simple program that will tell you if you need to water your plants today (seeing if it will rain today). I am using openweathermap api to do so. The api does not include rain as a variable like it does for temperature or humidity, instead it only appears as "rain" if it is raining as a part of the weather variable.

When I run my code below it never knows that it is raining even if the variable it is looking in includes rain. I want to know how I can find the word "rain" and print a message accordingly if it finds it in a variable.

After running my current code this is what I get if I print the `weathervar`:

`[{'id': 502, 'main': 'Rain', 'description': 'heavy intensity rain', 'icon': '10n'}]`

Even when the variable contains "rain" my code thinks it doesn't.

```
import requests, json
api_key = "someapikey"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
city_name = ("Brunei")
complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
response = requests.get(complete_url)
x = response.json()
if x["cod"] != "404":
    y = x["main"]
    current_temperature = y["temp"]
    weathervar = x["weather"]
else:
    print(" City Not Found ")

if 'Rain' in weathervar:
    print("You don't need to water your plants today.")
else:
    print("You need to water your plants today")
    print(weathervar)
```

Comment: I would recommend you to change you API-key in your account-information, since you already posted it here. This information should be private. If you share your API-keys, everyone who knows it can interact with the API with your credentials. Since you only have a certain amount of calls per time, sharing this information is not only insecure, but other people could use the API at your expense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `weathervar` is a list of dictionaries, you should check

```
if any(item['main'] == 'Rain' for item in weathervar):
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry, I'll leave the next one to you.

Comment: :-). Good use of `any()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
import requests, json
api_key = "someapikey"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
city_name = ("Brunei")
complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
response = requests.get(complete_url)
x = response.json()
if x["cod"] != "404":
        y = x["main"]
        current_temperature = y["temp"]
        weathervar = x["weather"][0]

else:
    print(" City Not Found ")

if 'Rain' in weathervar.values():
    print("You don't need to water your plants today.")

else:
    print("You need to water your plants today")
    print(weathervar)
```

First you have to convert the array to a proper dictionary. Then you can ask for the values of the dictionary with `.values()`.

Comment: Did you just provided your actual API key?